# How to send data to php server and receive data in php server using POST and httpurl connection

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

I am making an app and in that app I need to send data to php server and receive data at php server and vice versa. I am unable to send data from android app to php server ? can you please tell me how to do that ? 
This is my code for sending data to server.

```
public class EventServiceHandler
{
    String data;
    DoSomething d = new DoSomething();

    public EventServiceHandler() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    d.execute();
}
public void getObject()
{   
    String s = "http://www.example.com/thisisthis.php";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(s);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(100000);
        connection.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        response=connection.getResponseCode();
        String name="sateesh";
        String testing=URLEncoder.encode("name", "utf-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "utf-8");
        out.write(testing);     
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)

    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}

private  class DoSomething extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getObject();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

This is code on php server for receiving data on server.

```
<?php

if($_POST)
{
    $name = urldecode($_POST['name']);
    echo $name;
    error_log($name,0);
    echo "  ok";
}

else if(is_null($_POST) OR empty($_POST))
{
    error_log("empty or null",0);
    echo "in else if";

}

else
{
    echo "<br>";
    echo "in else";
}
echo "just";
```

?>

How do I know I am receiving data, how I make sure that data is being received.
I am new to php and have never used http classes in android.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy and paste this JSONParser.java file into your src folder

   [json parser class](http://androidtoserve.net46.net/JSONParser.java)
2. Write following code in your activity of android project.

public class CreateDailyReports extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
EditText edRTitle,edRDesc;
Button btnCreateReport;

String userId,cmid;

private ProgressDialog pdialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
int success=0;

private static String url_create_daily_reports = "";

private static String url_send_message = "";


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_daily_reports);

    initializeControls();

    btnCreateReport.setOnClickListener(this);



}


public void initializeControls(){


    edRTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextOfReportTitle);
    edRDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextOfReportDescription);
    btnCreateReport = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOfCreateReport);



}




public class CreateDReports extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateDailyReports.this);
        pdialog.setMessage("Wait... ");
        pdialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        pdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pdialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
    {

        String empid = userId;
        String sRtitle = edRTitle.getText().toString();
        String sRdesc = edRDesc.getText().toString();



        // Building Parameters

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eid",empid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rtitle",sRtitle));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rdesc",sRdesc));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid",cmid));


        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_daily_reports, "POST", params);

            //Log.i("login", json.toString());

            try 
            {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG

                success = json.getInt("success");




            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        } // doinbackground ends


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
{
    pdialog.dismiss();


        if(success==1){

        Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(CreateDailyReports.this, "Your Report has been Created", 10);
              myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
              myToast.show();   

              new SendDailyReports().execute();


        }
        else
        {
            Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(CreateDailyReports.this, "Your Reprot has not been Created", 10);
              myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
              myToast.show();

        }


        }

    } // update status of product auction over




@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int id = v.getId();

    if(id==btnCreateReport.getId()){



        new CreateDReports().execute();


    }



  }
```

}
 3. php script

```
<?php
```

$value1 = $_REQUEST["rtitle"];
$value2 = $_REQUEST["rdesc"];

```
// connect to your database


$result = mysql_query(" insert into table(field1,field2) values('$value1','$value2' )" );   
if($result == 1)
{
    // successfully inserted
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else
{
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

}
```

?>

Comment: Is my code on php is right ?

Comment: check my post, i have edited, it will insert values into your table and then will send response into json

Comment: and no, your php code is not right, because it should send json to your android app.

Comment: What is I have no database right now ? can you tell me a way without database. And on thing more is it necessary to send and receive JSon objects ?

Comment: without database , where your data you will save ? and yes it is necessary to send and receive JSON objects, without JSON you can not . and other option is XML if you don't want to use JSON.